# Closure compiler renames properties despite externs

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm creating a web-app and I use the closure compiler (v.20230411.0.0) to optimize the performance. In this app I create a popup and use `postMessage()` for the communication between the main window and the popup. For the communication I created a `Message` class. An instance of this class will be send and received that way. I compile the code twice with `--dependency_mode PRUNE` with different entry points. The `Message` class is used by both parts of the web-app. That is why it's properties shouldn't be renamed.

Here is the `Message` class as well as the enums `MessageTopic` and `MessageCommand`. In this example I only included files, whose property and variable names shouldn't be renamed or removed, so there is no need for the dependency mode here.

```js
// ###########################   message.js  ##################################

import MessageTopic from "./messagetopic.js";
import MessageCommand from "./messagecommand.js";

/**
 * A message for the communication between the main and the mod screen.
 * @template T
 */
class Message {
  /**
   * Constructor of {@link Message}.
   *
   * @param {!T} messageData - The transmitted data.
   * @param {!MessageTopic} messageTopic - The part of the app the message is about.
   * @param {!MessageCommand} messageCommand - The operation that should be executed with the data.
   */
  constructor (messageData, messageTopic, messageCommand) {
    /**
     * The data of this message.
     * @const {T}
     */
    this.data = messageData;

    /**
     * The part of the app the message is about.
     * @const {MessageTopic}
     */
    this.topic = messageTopic;

    /**
     * The operation that should be executed with the data.
     * @const {MessageCommand}
     */
    this.command = messageCommand;
  }
}

export default Message;

// ###########################   messagetopic.js  ##################################

/**
 * Enum for the topic this message is about.
 * @enum {number}
 *
 * @readonly
 */
const MessageTopic = {
  /** The topic of this message is the view system. */
  VIEW: 0,
  /** The topic of this message is the team system. */
  TEAM: 1
};

Object.freeze(MessageTopic);

export default MessageTopic;

// ###########################   messagecommand.js  ##################################

/**
 * Enum for the command that should be executed on the message target.
 * @enum {number}
 *
 * @readonly
 */
const MessageCommand = {
  /** A new object should be added. */
  ADD: 0,
  /** An object should be removed. */
  REMOVE: 1,
  /** An object should be shown. */
  SHOW: 2
};

Object.freeze(MessageCommand);

export default MessageCommand;
```

And here are the extern files:

```js
// ###########################   message.extern.js  ##################################

/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * A message for the communication between the main and the mod screen.
 * @template T
 */
class Message {
  /**
   * Constructor of {@link Message}.
   *
   * @param {!T} messageData - The transmitted data.
   * @param {!MessageTopic} messageTopic - The part of the app the message is about.
   * @param {!MessageCommand} messageCommand - The operation that should be executed with the data.
   */
  constructor (messageData, messageTopic, messageCommand) {
    /**
     * The data of this message.
     * @const {T}
     * @nocollapse
     */
    this.data = messageData;

    /**
     * The part of the app the message is about.
     * @const {MessageTopic}
     * @nocollapse
     */
    this.topic = messageTopic;

    /**
     * The operation that should be executed with the data.
     * @const {MessageCommand}
     * @nocollapse
     */
    this.command = messageCommand;
  }
}

// ###########################   messagetopic.extern.js  ##################################

/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * Enum for the topic this message is about.
 * @enum {number}
 *
 * @readonly
 */
const MessageTopic = {
  /** The topic of this message is the view system. */
  VIEW: 0,
  /** The topic of this message is the team system. */
  TEAM: 1
};

// ###########################   messagecommand.extern.js  ##################################

/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * Enum for the command that should be executed on the message target.
 * @enum {number}
 *
 * @readonly
 */
const MessageCommand = {
  /** A new object should be added. */
  ADD: 0,
  /** An object should be removed. */
  REMOVE: 1,
  /** An object should be shown. */
  SHOW: 2
};
```

When I call the closure compiler like this:

```sh
google-closure-compiler --warning_level VERBOSE --js message/* --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file build/message.js
```

it generates this `build/message.js`:

```js
Object.freeze({VIEW:0,TEAM:1});Object.freeze({ADD:0,REMOVE:1,SHOW:2});
```

---

It doesn't give me any errors or warnings. But in the result the properties were still renamed or removed. In my project, where the `Message` class is actually used, its properties are being renamed. Only the `data` property stays the same.

Adding the `--extern` flag with the extern files, gives me the same result. I can see that the closure compiler recognizes the files as extern files, because:

1. Using the `--output_manifest` flag I can see, that the extern files are not seen as source files. Yet they are in the `message/` directory as well.
2. Intentionally adding syntax errors in an extern file results in an error message from the compiler.

---

**What might be the problem? Is there a way to get any information about the processed extern files in the compilation process? Do I write the extern files the wrong way?**